# C#: can't access public constructor in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm new to C# and am confused that I can't access a class or its constructor in a unit test (following the MSDN tutorial for unit testing).

I have a class like this:

```
namespace FooBar {

    class Foo {
        public double bar { get; set; }

        public Foo() {
            // empty constructor
        }
    }
}
```

The errors I get when I try build a simple unit test is `FooBar.Foo is inaccessible due to its protection level` and `The type FooBar.Foo has no constructors defined.`

**Q:** Are both of these due to classes being inherently private within a namespace? If so, how can I test my public methods?

Comment: The _class_ `Foo` is inaccessible. You didn't make it `public`.

Comment: can I test it and still keep it private?

Comment: Well it's not `private`, it's `internal`. You'll either have to include the tests in the same assembly or make the internals visible to your test assembly. But in the end, it'll just be easier to make it `public`.

Comment: okay thanks, ill just do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes are internal by default in C#, meaning only other classes within the same assembly can access them.

Adding public to the class definition will enable you to access the class and its constructor.

```
...
public class Foo { ...
```

Comment: It would be more correct to say that classes are internal by default in the absence of a modifier.

Comment: Ah, thanks -- I fixed the wording to be more correct.